# Can't save data into multiple tables using ASP.NET EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

On a page on my website a person can change information about a device.

This data comes from 2 different tables. Saving data into the `DeviceStatus` table is no problem.

But for some reason I can't save the `Active` field into the `concremodeDevice` table. Saving all other data from this table is no problem.

Code:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,DeviceConfig_id,Device_statustypes_id,ConcremoteDevice_id,Employee_1,Employee_2,Sign_Date,Active")] DeviceStatus deviceStatus, ConcremoteDevice concremoteDevice)
{
    var Conn = (from d in db.DeviceStatus
                join s in db.Device_statustypes on d.Device_statustypes_id equals s.id
                join b in db.ConcremoteDevice on d.ConcremoteDevice_id equals b.id
                join c in db.DeviceConfig on d.DeviceConfig_id equals c.Device_config_id
                select new { s.id, Model = d.id });

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(deviceStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    //    ViewBag.device_type_id = new SelectList(db.DeviceType, "device_type_id", "device_type", concremoteDevice.id);
    return View(deviceStatus);
}
```

Page:

```
@model ConcremoteDeviceManagment.Models.DeviceStatus

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>ConcremoteDevice</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DeviceConfig_id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Device_statustypes_id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Serie nummer", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConcremoteDevice_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConcremoteDevice_id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Device Type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DeviceConfig.DeviceType.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DeviceConfig.DeviceType.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Config ID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DeviceConfig.Device_config_id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Medewerker 1", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Medewerker 2", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee_2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Employee_2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Signeer datum", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sign_Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sign_Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Huidige status", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("StatusList", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Device_Statustypes.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("In Gebruik", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="col-md-10 checkbox">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConcremoteDevice.Active)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConcremoteDevice.Active, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ConcremoteDevice] (
    [id]     NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Active] BIT           NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_ConcremoteDevice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 65)
);
```

So my question is if someone knows why I can't save `Active`.

As suggested by pinkfloydx33 in the comments I have at some point also tried to set the state of concremodeDevice, but this gave me the next error:

```
The key field 'id' cannot have a value of null. A non-null value is required for the key fields defined on type 'ConcremoteDevice'
```

BTW, don't know if ASP.NET of EF6 has anything to do with this, but included it just to be sure.

Comment: Don't you need to set the state of `concremoteDevice` like you do for the other one?

Comment: @mjwills Really nothing happens. for as far as I know I don't get a error, but it just does not save it

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 had that at some point but that just gave me errors

Comment: Please use `Chrome Developer Tools` to show the payload being POSTed to the endpoint. Include that in your question.

Comment: Can you share those errors?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 updated the question with the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "id,DeviceConfig_id,Device_statustypes_id,ConcremoteDevice_id,Employee_1,Employee_2,Device_statustypes_id,Sign_Date,Active")] DeviceStatus deviceStatus, ConcremoteDevice concremoteDevice)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(deviceStatus).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.Entry(concremoteDevice).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Device Edited Successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(deviceStatus);
        }
```

And view:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>ConcremoteDevice</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DeviceConfig_id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Device_statustypes_id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ConcremoteDevice.id)
```